# Grid.Mvc.Ajax initialising issues

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

I am attempting to get Grid.Mvc.Ajax running in a MVC project, but the documentation is very poor. There are two issues as the moment - first one relates the Index ActionResult. I have tried to define a new grid a number of ways but it always throws 'IQueryable(Of DateGridModels)' is an interface type and cannot be used as an expression..

Examples of what I have tried

```
Dim vGrid = CType(New Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGridFactory().CreateAjaxGrid(IQueryable(Of DateGridModels), 1, False, 5), Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGrid(Of DateGridModels))

Dim vGrid2 = CType(New AjaxGridFactory().CreateAjaxGrid(Of DateGridModels)(IQueryable(Of DateGridModels), 1, False, 5), AjaxGrid(Of DateGridModels))
```

[image: AjaxGridFactory]

The other issue, not directly related to the grid but more general MVC is this

```
 @code
   @Html.RenderPartial("_DataGrid", Model)
 End Code
```

Returns 'Expression does not produce a value'

============================ EDIT ========================

In response to Mark C in comments

**Partial**

```
@Imports GridMvc.Html
@Imports GridMvc.Sorting
@ModelType Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGrid(Of DateGridModels)
```

**View**

```
@ModelType MainModels
```

**Main Model**

```
Public Class MainModels
  Public Property CalendarM() As CalendarModels
  Public Property GridM() As List(Of MaintGrid)
End Class
```

**Grid Model**

```
Public Class DateGridModels
  Public Property FirstName() As String
  Public Property LastName() As String
End Class
```

Comment: What if you changed `IQueryable` to `Queryable`?

Comment: 'Queryable' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments... Thank you for responding, this one is driving me NUTS

Comment: In the Documentation, it initializes `CreateAjaxGrid` with a concrete implementation of `List<T>` and not an interface. Why don't you use a `List<DateGridModels>` instead? Edit: Sorry, just noticed this is for VB and not C#. Just implement a new List of `DateGridModels`

Comment: Tried list and got the following error -  

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MaintenanceWeb.DateGridModels]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MaintenanceWeb.DateGridModels]'.

Comment: So I think you may need to change every instance of IQueryable to List for this (in your View, etc) unless you have the static method option of .AsQueryable() available to you.

Comment: I'll edit the original post to show more code. Where did you find the documentation on CreateAjaxGrid?

Comment: Did you changed the IQueryable instances and you're still getting an error? And I just went to twit page and clicked the Documentation link lol

Comment: You need to call `AsQueryable()` on your list I believe.

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'CreateAjaxGrid' accepts this number of arguments. Can you provide a link for the documentation, all I can find is https://gridmvcajax.codeplex.com/documentation - I think IQueryable is hard-wired into IAjaxGrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instantiate the Grid exactly as the documentation specifies to do so, like:

```
Dim vm = New List(Of DateGridModels)() From { _
    New DateGridModels() With { _
        Key .FirstName = "John", _
        Key .LastName = "Doe" _
    } _
}.AsQueryable()
Dim ajaxGridFactory = New Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGridFactory()
Dim grid = ajaxGridFactory.CreateAjaxGrid(vm, 1, False)
```

It looks like the list doesnt need to be implemented `AsQueryable()`, probably because they are doing some `linq` statements in the Grid.

Comment: If I remove original ModelType it works, although sorting seems to postback like Grid.Mvc, could be I haven't implemented a script for that yet. The main problem is that I have a host of other controls that use a different Model but it blows out at Html.RenderPartial("_DataGrid", Model.DateM)... Thank you for your patience :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Where are you removing ModelType and it is working?

Comment: Originally the ModelType was set to MainModels, that in turn point to other models - so in the controls they are set as Model.Model1, Model.Model2 and so on - with the grid I set to Model.DateM ( DateGridModels) and it blew out as it just picked up MainModels... ModelType was changed in the main view to get it to work

Comment: Yes and no - can get it load, but then the rest of the controls on the same view are useless :-(

Comment: In the end I had to go a slightly different way as I needed a method to get all the other controls to work as well, but have marked this as the answer and voted it up - thank you for your help :-)

Comment: That sucks you had to create such a big work around for it, but I am really glad you got it to work! Make sure you update your question with your solution (or post it as an answer).. Great job!